# Angular - Firebase - cannot properly fetch values in a node with nested nodes

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Exported .json of my database is the following:

```
"staff" : {
    "moderators" : [ "BdKThY8WaCTPum8vOlnuegeatas2", "HhQjBRSuI2ToFaNKEX01KXO8U1O2", "IWSaNSAQLZf9g56ItR3KthTmiXt2" ],
    "adminID" : "SkVFaizkNOaQXhqVEbHNS5Fuk6D3"
}
```

I wish to obtain an Array which contains all the **values** in the `moderators` array and the `adminID` **value** as well.

However, after obtaining the observable at that node:

```
this.af.retrieveObservable(`staff/`).pipe(
  map(members => {
      console.log("????", members);
  }).subscribe();
```

My `members` would look like this:
[image]

What would be the proper way to obtain all the member's IDs into a single array?